# Coroutine job never completing

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Given this piece of code

```
fun main() {
    val job = Job()
    val scope = GlobalScope + job

    scope.launch {
        println("working!")
        delay(1000L)is ms)
        println("done!")
        // how do i finish the job originally associated with this scope?
    }


    runBlocking {
        job.join()
        println("job done")
    }
}
```

I have a custom coroutine scope for my application, and i'm associating a job with this scope like that, reason being i want all the new coroutines that are created from this scope to be the children of this job, if i cancel it i want everything in it to be cancelled.

But main job itself is never completing. How do i complete the main job when the task is done? or failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify your code to something like this:

```
val job = Job()
runBlocking {
    job.join()
}
```

If you run this code you will see that it also never completes. That is because `job.join()` suspends until the given job reaches a terminal state which is either `completed` or `canceled` (see [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/)).

When you create a job using some coroutine builder (like `.launch {...}`) you do not need to complete it by yourself. But since you have created it using a factory method `Job()` it is now your responsibility to complete it.

You can also find more detailed explanation [here](https://kt.academy/article/cc-job).

Comment: well i asked it forever ago but the point was that scope is associated with the job its not dead code... the intent was to have a job associated with the routine and when cancelled cancel it and all child subroutines.

Comment: accepting yours since you seem to have no points )

Answer (score 3):

The main job works only as the parent job and will never complete.
But you could wait for all children to complete:

```
runBlocking {
    job.children.forEach { it.join() }
    println("job done")
}
```

Alternatively you should go with Eugene's solution and invoke the `join` method of the `Job` you just started, instead of the main job.

Comment: "main job works only as the parent job and will never complete" - could you please link the corresponding documentation? I try to understand this... :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several functions to wait for a `Job()` object to complete and to cancel it. You may pick one from the list

```
job.cancel()
job.join()
job.cancelAndJoin()
```

Only the first function is not a `suspend` function, so you may call it from every other function, not necessarily a `suspend` functions

There is a better way - the `launch{..}` function already returns `Job` object from the call. You may simplify the code to say

```
val job = GlobalScope.launch { .. }
```

that `Job` object will automatically complete when launch block is over or failed with an exception