# Kotlin how to wait on the job to finish?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The below example of code should run out of the box.

I am attempting to spin off 2 threads and wait for them to finish from the main thread.

However, when I join() on the job, the join() never lets go indefinitely, blocking the main thread.

How to appropriately join on the job?

```
package example.threading

import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext

interface Server {
    fun start()
    fun stop()
}

class ServerImpl : Server, CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Default + job

    override fun start() {
        println("Starting server")

        launch {
            println("Running server work in thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            delay(2000)
            println("Server background thread 1 completed")
        }

        launch {
            println("Running additional server work in thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            delay(1500)
            println("Server background thread 2 completed")
        }
    }

    suspend fun joinOnJob() {
        job.join()
    }

    override fun stop() {
        println("Stopping server")
        job.cancel()
    }
}


fun main() = runBlocking {
    go()
}


private suspend fun go() {
    println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    println("Example where there server is aborted prior to finishing:")
    val server = ServerImpl()
    server.start()

    println("Waiting on job to finish")
    server.joinOnJob()

    println("Server done processing from main thread")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coroutine job never completing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753724/coroutine-job-never-completing)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is your idea here, because it seems you mix two different concurrency patterns. One is forking a task into two concurrent subtasks and joining on them. Another is creating a service which we start manually and it runs continuously until we stop it.

The reason why it doesn't work is that if we manually create a `Job()` or `CoroutineScope()`, then they remain active indefinitely, until we manually cancel or complete them. This is expected behavior for services with manual `start()/stop()`, because we expect them to run until we stop them.

If you only need to fork into subtasks and then join, then I think you should not at all use this service pattern, but instead create a simple suspend function:

```kotlin
suspend fun foo() = coroutineScope {
    launch { subTask1() }
    launch { subTask2() }
}
```

However, it is possible I miss some context in your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, each launch adds a job to the parent job - from the ServerImpl class. Then you assume that join on this parent job will wait for the child jobs to complete which will also complete the parent job. This is a false assumption.

When you call join() on this parent job, you're asking to wait until this specific job completes, not until its children complete. The parent job does not complete when its children complete; rather, it completes when it is cancelled or when complete() is called on it explicitly.

You can fix your code in various ways, one would be to store the jobs created by launch and join on them. Another is to make finishing childreen jobs to complete the parent job.

First solution would look as follows:

First add:

```
private val childJobs = mutableListOf<Job>()
```

to your ServerImpl class, then add the child jobs to it:

```
childJobs.add(launch { ... } )
```

and in your joinOnJob:

```
override fun joinOnJob() = runBlocking {
    childJobs.forEach { it.join() }
}
```

waits for the childs.

The second solution is to complete the parent job when the child finishes:

add following method call to your launches:

```
    launch { ...
    }.invokeOnCompletion { checkJobCompletion() }
```

then, in checkJobCompletion - complete the parent job:

```
private fun checkJobCompletion() {
    if (coroutineContext[Job]?.children?.all { it.isCompleted } == true) {
        job.complete()
    }
}
```